Building tooltips in Svelte or NextUI or anything else?
I'm trying to do something relatively simple, but I'm in no way a designer--this would basically be a chunk of custom code in SquareSpace.
I'm trying to do an interactive series of annotations to images in either SS or WP. Ideally, it'd look something like this: https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2022/08/26/us/trump-search-affidavit-release.html
It looks like the example above was built in Svelte, I saw another tool called NextUI that might work. Is there a relatively simple template that has the following

Ability to hang a tooltip over an image.
A "next" function to jump to the next tooltip.
Hopefully all in one chunk of code that I can embed in a SquareSpace site?

Any help would be beloved.
I'm just getting started!
